# Imageflip on imagemap, but keep the map coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a rather complex imagemap with several mapped areas.
Most of the mapped areas are just mapped for mouseovers and links. But some arease have a `JS onClick()`  which results in an imageflip. The new, flipped image is basically the old image, with a few "new things" on it.

Two things need to happen which I cannot figure out:

1. The new image needs to stay there. What is happening no is that as soon as I move the mouse out of the mapped area, it flipps back to the old image.
2. I need the imagemap (of the "old" image) to work on the new image, which appears on the flip.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//PRELOAD IMAGES FOR CLICK AND MOUSEOVER
cuentaBoca = new Image(655, 338)
cuentaBoca.src = "imagenes_png/pag2/cuentame_bocadilla.png";

cuenta = new Image(655, 338)
cuenta.src = "imagenes_png/pag2/cuentame_h.png";

//JS FUNCTION FOR CLICK
function bocadillaC() {
document.getElementById('garfio').src = cuentaBoca.src;
}

//JS FUNCTION FOR MOUSEOVER
function cuentaH() {
document.getElementById('garfio').src = cuenta.src;
return true;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- INSERT THE PICTURE -->
<img name="garfio" id="garfio" src="imagenes_png/pag2/base.png" width="655" height="338" border="0"  usemap="#m_garfio" alt="" />

<!-- CREATE THE MAP -->
<map name="m_garfio" id="m_garfio">

    <area shape="poly" id="bocadilla" coords="7,205,12,197,20,191,24,189,34,185,45,182,58,180,74,180,86,180,94,181,103,182,112,185,114,186,130,178,135,177,137,179,134,184,130,192,135,195,138,199,142,204,143,209,138,218,125,227,113,231,100,235,86,236,70,236,53,235,41,233,34,231,23,226,15,221,11,217,8,212,7,205" 
     onMouseOver="cuentaH()" onClick="bocadillaC(); return false" alt="" />

</map>
</div>
```

Here a Fiddel http://jsfiddle.net/emedrs9n/
Clicking on the "Cuentame" (balloon) has the `onClick()` effect

Comment: Please, make an example http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @dizel3d Just realised it, sorry added it.

Comment: You still haven't posted the `onMouseOver` function `cuentaH()`. I tried a simple JS test to change the background colour of `<span id="myArea" onMouseOver="setbg();">Hello World!</span>` and it stays as the new colour after the mouse has left the rollover area. I did that with `document.getElementById('myArea').style.backgroundColor = "blue";`

Comment: @WeatherVane added the function for `cuentaH()`. How would I replace it not with a color, but with a preloaded image? I thought thats what `...().src` does?

Comment: Thanks but your functions are using id "garfio" whereas the HTML section with `onMouseOver` and `onClick` has the id "bocadilla".

Comment: @WeatherVane Thats because I did not slice up the image into several `divs`. Basically, the whole image with the id `garfio` is replaced. Changing it from `garfio` to `bocadilla` does result in no effect at all. The picture is not flipping.

Comment: I repeated my simple test setting a *different* tag's background colour, again it stays changed after rollout. Sorry can't go further.

Comment: @WeatherVane I´d appreciate it if you could demonstrate that in the fiddle I made... Basically I do what you are doing, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redefine the `original` function on click. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dizel3d/o5d0sxbj/)

```
function bocadillaC() {
    cuentaH = original = bocadillaC;

    // redefine other functions
    leftH = function() {
        document.getElementById('garfio').src = left_with_yellow_cloud.src;
    };
    rightH = function() {
        document.getElementById('garfio').src = right_with_yellow_cloud.src;
    };
    cuentaH = function() {
        document.getElementById('garfio').src = cuenta_with_yellow_cloud.src;
    };
    // ...

    document.getElementById('garfio').src = cuentaBoca.src;
}
```

And you need to redefine other functions with images. But, for example, for [this](http://www.fonag.org.ec/inicio/images/Slide/aprender_jugando/agua/base_iz.png) state there is no a similar image with yellow cloud.

But in fact **you need to use power of HTML/CSS**, don't draw image on each case and do it simpler without image map.

Comment: Sorry if my title led to confusion. I do not want to flip or rotate the image. An imageflip is triggerd on a clickevent or mouseover. I need the new image which appears on click to be permanent, with the working imagemap

Comment: Ok, I have replace my answer. Does it what you want?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you built such a large jsfiddle before you had it working simply.

Comment: Sweet, that does half the trick. What I do not understand is how I should redifine the other functions. As soon as I enter another mapped area now, its flipping back to the original picture.

Comment: Never mind bloating your example by preloading images and having loads of areas. Write a simple program with one or maybe two areas and get it working in the simplest case possible. Why would anyone here want to step through all that code? But by the time you have done that, you might have answered your question.

Comment: @Maccaroni, you need to make similar images with yellow cloud. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I think, the question is about this specific example http://jsfiddle.net/emedrs9n/. Read the question again.

Comment: @dizel3d thanks for your answere but I still do not get it. If I have the images with the yellow cloud, how do I tell my imagemap when to call which function? How does it know that once I clicked on the "cuentame" its supposed to call the function with the `left_with_yellow_cloud` picutre, while when the "cuentame" is not clicked, its supposed to call the function with the `left` but without the yellow cloud.

Comment: @Maccaroni, after first click the `bocadillaC` will redefine all functions: leftH, rightH, ... And they will be always set new images. If you give me pictures with yellow cloud, I will repair the example.

Comment: @dizel3d I previously did what you say before that last comment. In response to OP's latest jfiddle, when I started to read it, it was all about preloading images. My point stands - write the simplest possible code to isolate the problem.

Comment: @dizel3d http://www.fonag.org.ec/inicio/images/Slide/aprender_jugando/agua/cloud_left.png and http://www.fonag.org.ec/inicio/images/Slide/aprender_jugando/agua/cloud_right.png 
I appreciate your help! If you need different pictures, please let me know.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, there is a reason why I preload the image and do not stack them simply over another...

Comment: @dizel3d oh wow, awesome! Cant believe it. Could you explain how the JS (or HTML?) knows which function to use after the click? I see that is working, but I wonder how JS knows to use these functions after the click?!

Comment: @Maccaroni, you defined `leftH` and other functions in JS code as properties of global `window` object, and bound them in HTML (`onMouseOver="leftH()"`). But after the click the `bocadillaC` function replaced values of `leftH` and other `window` properties with new anonymous functions (`leftH = function() { ... }`), which set images with yellow cloud.
Learn more about JS/HTML/CSS.

Comment: @dizel3d Ah, I understand. Thanks. I am learning every day about JS and HTML :) Step by step!

Answer (score 0):

This does what you seem to ask. Two images are displayed. When I roll the mouse over the upper image, the lower image changes and does not change back. The images vane2.jpg and vane2.png are mirror images.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setimage () {
    document.getElementById('hisArea').src = "vane2.png";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="myArea" onMouseOver="setimage();" width="176" height="176" src="vane1.jpg">
<BR>
<img id="hisArea" width="176" height="176" src="vane2.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```